# python logging - rotate file each message logged

Tags: python, logging

Having troubles creating a rotating file handler which will rotate on each message I log.

example:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger(...)
logger.info("I'm written to my own file")
logger.info("I'm written to my own file #2")
logger.info("I'm written to my own file #3")
```

Any ideas how to implement such handler?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RotatingFileHandler [doRollover](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler.doRollover) method. Here is an example:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

class CustomHandler(logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        self.doRollover()
        super().emit(record)


LOG_FILENAME = "logging_rotatingfile_example.out"

logger = logging.getLogger("MyLogger")
logger.addHandler(CustomHandler(LOG_FILENAME, backupCount=50))
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.info("I'm written to my own file")
logger.info("I'm written to my own file #2")
logger.info("I'm written to my own file #3")
```